# How to show the Crystal-Report in a panel in same page

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports-2008

I have a GridView consist of multiple columns. The last column has a button on click of which it shows a Crystal-Report in next page.
I want to show  the Crystal-Report in same page inside a panel. How to do that

Comment: you can use jQuery dialog for showing the chart. On button click open the box and add the page in it which contains the chart. On close you will be on the same page.

Comment: Can you share the code that you have so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the possible way to go is to use iframe. The HTML iframe Element represents a nested browsing context, effectively embedding another HTML page into the current page.

So iframe element can be placed inside panel you need and can display (load) content of page with Crystal-Report. Basically what u need to do is put the crystal report on another page and have the IFrame render that page as its source.